# How can i host Flutter web app in an arbitrary element?

Tags: flutter

Kevin Moore(Product manager of Flutter team) told in an official youtube video that now we can host our flutter web app in an arbitrary element. Here is [his speech](https://youtu.be/PY42FysQTgw?t=193). How can i achieve this?

I did make an application and I want to show it in a specific area on the display on the web. I hope, arbitrary element is the best way to do this as Kevin told.